Does this tangent developable-like surface have a cusp along a curve or is it smooth?
Consider the following surface $X$ which is a subvariety of the full flag variety $Y=\{0 \subset V_1 \subset V_2 \subset V\}$ where $V$ is a fixed three-dimensional vector space and ${\rm dim} V_i =i$. The surface $X$ is formed by full flags in $Y$ such that the line $\mathbb P(V_2)$ is tangent to a fixed quadric curve $Q$ in $\mathbb P(V)$. Question: is the surface $X$ smooth and isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ or is it singular in such a way that it has a cusp along $Q$ and has a one-to-one map from $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$?

You said what $V_2$ is, but you didn't say what $V_1$ is.

@Sasha Thank you very much! $V_1$ is an arbitrary one-dimensional subspace of the fixed three-dimensional vector space $V$ such that $V_1$ is a subspace of $V_2$

Then $X$ is the projectivization of the tautological bundle $\mathcal{U}_2$ over $Q$ (embedded into $\mathbb{P}(V^\vee)$ as the dual conic).

@Sasha Great, thank you very much! So from your answer it looks like $X$ is smooth and is isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$.

Yes. Another way to see this is the following. Consider the double covering $f : S \to \mathbb{P}(V)$ ramified over $Q$. Then $S$ is a smooth quadrics surface, hence $S \cong \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$. Now, note that $f$ maps the rulings of $S$ to tangents of $Q$. Thus, taking a point $s \in S$ to $(f(s),f(R_s))$ (where $R_s$ is the ruling passing through $s$) gives an isomorphism $S \cong X$.

@Sasha Thank you very much! So $X$ is not the tangent developable surface of $Q$ (the tangent developable surface of a curve $C$ in projective space is the union of all tangent lines to $C$)? I read that the tangent developable surface of a curve $C$ tends to have a cusp along $C$. I guess in this case the projective space is too small, but for a Veronese curve $C$ in a bigger projective space the tangent developable surface has a cusp along $C$.

The restriction to a rational normal curve $C\cong \mathbb{P}^1$ of degree d in $\mathbb{P}^d$ of the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{P}^d$ is a rank $d$ locally free sheaf isomorphic to a direct sum of invertible sheaves of rank $d+1$ on $C$.

@JasonStarr Does this have consequences for the tangent developable surface of the rational normal curve?

Yes, since the restriction of the tangent bundle is a direct sum of invertible sheaves of equal degree, the associated projective space bundle is a product.
